# MongooseJS $inc not working when trying to increment

Tags: mongoose

I am making a discord bot for moderation, and I need to store the number of punishments in my database, this works like this: Every time you warn someone, the totalPunishments counter should increase by one as well as the warnings counter. By some googling, I found out about $inc statement. I tried using it, and the warnings counter increments fine. But the total counter isn't changed at all.

Here is my code:

```
await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
        try {
            const userInfo = await punishmentSchema.findOne({_id: guild.id, userId: member.id});

            if(userInfo) {
                await punishmentSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    _id: guild.id, 
                    userId: member.id
                }, {
                    $inc: {'totalPunishments': 1},
                    $inc: {'warnings': 1},
                    lastPunishment: timestamp('YYYYMMDDHHMM')
                })

            } else {
                await punishmentSchema.create({
                    _id: guild.id,
                    userId: member.id,
                    totalPunishments: 1,
                    warnings: 1,
                    mutes: 0,
                    kicks: 0,
                    lastPunishment: timestamp('YYYYMMDDHHMM')
                })
            }

            
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
```

And here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reqString = {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

const punishmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: reqString,
    userId: reqString,
    totalPunishments: Number,
    warnings: Number,
    mutes: Number,
    kicks: Number,
    lastPunishment: reqString
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', punishmentSchema);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to merge your 2 $inc props into one

```
$inc: {'totalPunishments': 1, 'warnings': 1},
```

Comment: Yeah man, thanks! can you please explain why this works?

Comment: well, because you can't use the same key for different key/value pairs in an object, and probrably the second $set overwrites the first or you are getting an exception